# How often we expect an event to occur in a given year regardless of location?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, frequency

I'm trying to determine how often an event will occur in a given year regardless
of location and determine a 95% confidence interval. I have the year, location, and how often it occur for the given year.

```
State           Year    Frequency per year
Colorado        1864    1
Colorado        1900    3
Colorado        1953    3
Colorado        1954    3
Colorado        1955    1
Colorado        1958    2
Colorado        1961    4
Colorado        1965    10
Colorado        1966    1
Colorado        1967    9
Colorado        1969    4
Colorado        1971    2
Colorado        1973    9
Colorado        1974    3
Colorado        1975    9
Colorado        1976    11
Colorado        1977    7
Colorado        1978    10
Colorado        1979    4
Colorado        1980    5
Colorado        1981    13
Colorado        1982    16
Colorado        1983    8
Colorado        1984    15
Colorado        1985    9
Colorado        1986    6
Colorado        1987    19
Colorado        1988    19
Colorado        1989    4
Colorado        1990    12
Colorado        1991    12
Colorado        1992    18
Colorado        1993    2
Colorado        1994    8
Colorado        1995    8
Colorado        1996    25
Colorado        1997    9
Colorado        1998    13
Colorado        1999    4
Colorado        2000    1
Colorado        2001    7
Colorado        2002    3
Colorado        2003    5
Colorado        2004    10
Colorado        2005    4
Colorado        2006    8
Colorado        2007    3
Colorado        2008    9
Colorado        2009    9
Colorado        2010    6
Colorado        2011    5
Colorado        2012    7
Colorado        2013    2
Colorado        2014    13
Colorado        2015    4
North Carolina  1874    1
North Carolina  1885    1
North Carolina  1893    2
North Carolina  1894    1
North Carolina  1896    1
North Carolina  1899    1
North Carolina  1950    2
North Carolina  1954    3
North Carolina  1956    1
North Carolina  1960    1
North Carolina  1961    4
North Carolina  1964    2
North Carolina  1965    10
North Carolina  1968    1
North Carolina  1969    4
North Carolina  1970    1
North Carolina  1973    9
North Carolina  1974    3
North Carolina  1975    9
North Carolina  1977    7
North Carolina  1978    10
North Carolina  1980    5
North Carolina  1982    16
North Carolina  1983    8
North Carolina  1984    15
North Carolina  1985    9
North Carolina  1988    19
North Carolina  1989    4
North Carolina  1990    12
North Carolina  1992    18
North Carolina  1994    8
North Carolina  1995    8
North Carolina  1996    25
North Carolina  1997    9
North Carolina  1998    13
North Carolina  1999    4
North Carolina  2001    7
North Carolina  2003    5
North Carolina  2004    10
North Carolina  2005    4
North Carolina  2006    8
North Carolina  2007    3
North Carolina  2008    9
North Carolina  2009    9
North Carolina  2010    6
North Carolina  2011    5
North Carolina  2012    7
North Carolina  2014    13
North Carolina  2015    4
```

How should I approach this problem?